# Остановка многопоточного сервера Java

Tags: многопоточность, сеть, клиент-сервер

Не могу остановить многопоточный сервер:

```
     import java.io.BufferedReader;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.InputStreamReader;
     import java.io.PrintStream;
     import java.net.ServerSocket;
     import java.net.Socket;
     import java.util.ArrayList;

     public class Server {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    ServerSocket server = null;
    Socket client = null;
    server = new ServerSocket(3456);
    System.out.println("Сервер ожидает подключения");
    try {
        while (true) {
            client = server.accept();
            new ThreadEchoHandler(client);
        }
    }
    finally {
        server.close();
    }
}
}


class ThreadEchoHandler extends Thread {
private Socket client = null;
String newMessage = new String("New");
String endMessage = new String("End");
String endConnection = new String("stop");
BufferedReader inputLine;
PrintStream out;

public ThreadEchoHandler(Socket socket)
{
    client = socket;
    start();
}

public void run()
{
    try {
        //Входной поток сервера
        inputLine = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        //Выходной поток сервера
        out = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader bRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        boolean flag = false;
        boolean flagEnd = false;
        ArrayList<String> clientmessages = new ArrayList<>();

        while (flagEnd != true)
        {
                try {
                    String checkConnection = inputLine.readLine();
                    if (checkConnection.equals(endConnection)) {
                        flagEnd = true;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Получено от клиента 1:"+checkConnection);
                        String clientmessage = new String();
                        while (clientmessages.size() != 5) {
                            clientmessage = inputLine.readLine();
                            System.out.println("Получено от клиента 2:"+clientmessage);
                            clientmessages.add(clientmessage);
                        }
                    }
                    //Производим вычиления
                    double number1 = new Double(Double.parseDouble(clientmessages.get(0)));
                    double number2 = new Double(Double.parseDouble(clientmessages.get(3)));
                    int action = new Integer(Integer.parseInt(clientmessages.get(1)));
                    double result = new Double("0");

                    switch (action) {
                        case 1: {
                            result = number1 + number2;
                        }
                        break;
                        case 2: {
                            result = number1 - number2;
                        }
                        break;
                        case 3: {
                            result = number1 * number2;
                        }
                        break;
                        case 4: {
                            result = number1 / number2;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    clientmessages.clear();
                    //Отправка сообщения клиенту
                    String sentMessage = new String();
                    sentMessage = Double.toString(result);
                    System.out.println("Отправлено клиенту:"+sentMessage);
                    //Отправляем сообщение
                    out.println(sentMessage);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Disconnect");
    this.disconnect();
}

public void disconnect() {
    try{
        this.inputLine.close();
        this.out.close();
        this.client.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Как завершить работу программы?

Comment: Возможно, при создании нового треда нужно ссылку на него сохранять в какой-то список, а при необходимости завершения работы, обойти этот список и вызвать стоп метод для каждого из его элементов?